# How can I obtain optimized varables from pyOpt as a list?

Tags: python, optimization

I have written a procedure to perform NSGA2 optimization using pyOpt, and but the solution prints out the optimized variables along with the respective constraints. I want to use the optimized variables for further analysis. How can I output a list of final design variables?

For example, the output from the optimization looks like:

```
NSGA-II Solution to Reservoir Operations Optimization

Objective Function: benefit

Solution: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total Time:                  358.4790
Total Function Evaluations:          

Objectives:
    Name        Value        Optimum
         f        -19539.3             0

    Variables (c - continuous, i - integer, d - discrete):
    Name    Type       Value       Lower Bound  Upper Bound
        x_0       c    1523.796492       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_1       c    5064.324074       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_2       c    2162.772045       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_3       c    3177.890807       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_4       c    2318.221792       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_5       c    1801.992503       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_6       c    4205.181367       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_7       c    1500.013593       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_8       c    1500.026373       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_9       c    1500.002134       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_10      c    1500.000983       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_11      c    1500.007746       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_12      c    1500.001387       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_13      c    1500.023302       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_14      c    1500.019080       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 
        x_15      c    1500.001947       1.50e+03     9.00e+03 

    Constraints (i - inequality, e - equality):
    Name    Type                    Bounds
        g_0           i       -1.00e+21 <= -265630.357944 <= 0.00e+00
        g_1           i       -1.00e+21 <= -274500.633582 <= 0.00e+00
        g_2           i       -1.00e+21 <= -277659.633602 <= 0.00e+00
```

However, I just want to get the values of x_0, x_1... as list.

Comment: Type some code, to understand you better

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue you must save the results that come out of the optimisation problem into a variable

Therefore, you have to do something like

```
from pyOpt import Optimization, ALHSO

# Make the objective function
def of(x):
    return x**2, [], 0

# Setup the optimisation problem
opt_prob = Optimization('min_sq', of)
opt_prob.addVar('x', 'c', value=10, lower=-10, upper=10)
opt_eng = ALHSO()
opt_eng.setOption('fileout', 0)
sol = opt_eng(opt_prob)
```

Form this point on, the resulting variable (sol) will be a list with:

- Objective function
- Decision variables
- Dictionary additional information

  ```
  >>sol

  (array([  1.15734425e-08]),
   array([ 0.00010758]),
   {'fevals': 398,
    'opt_g': array([], dtype=float64),
    'time': 0.007999897003173828})
  ```

I hope this do the trick

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can get the values of the variables out of the solution struct:

```py
import pyOpt

def fun(x):
    o = (1-x[0])**2 + 1*(x[1] - x[0]**2)**2
    return o, [], 0

opt_prob = pyOpt.Optimization('rosenbrock_11', fun)
slsqp = pyOpt.SLSQP()
opt_prob.addObj('f')
opt_prob.addVar('x', 'c', value=0, lower=-10, upper=10)
opt_prob.addVar('y', 'c', value=2, lower=-10, upper=10)
slsqp(opt_prob)

res = opt_prob.solution(0)
vs = res.getVarSet()
x = [vs[key].value for key in vs]
print(x)
# [1.000128987486733, 1.0002557449445557]
```